# How long until you can see your town history?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

How long does your town tree have to grow until you can sit on it and see your town's history?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [this](http://bidoofcrossing.tumblr.com/post/39210951143/want-to-know-how-to-grow-your-town-tree-well-now) can help. I didn't know of the town history feature, but my guess would be that you'll unlock it as soon as you get it to the "fully grown" status, which means 500 hours + 500 days.

Answer (score 5):

Based on the other answer and the fact that I was able to see my town's history as of yesterday (I got the game on release date, which was about 50 days ago), I'd say 50 days and 50 hours.

[image: town history]